# Maintain a session for one field in yii

Tags: php, yii

```
Yii::app()->session['uniqueid'] = $this->username;//got error in this line

public function authenticate()
    {
            $record= User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
                if($record===null)
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
                else if($record->password!==$this->password)
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
                else
        {

            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
                    //    $this->setState('group_id', $user->group_id);
                        // Store the role in a session:
                       $this->setState('role', $record->accessrole);
                      // $this->user_id = $record->user_id;

    }
```

and i want to use this username in different model called signup model. what is error in this line
in signnp model i use

```
$id=Yii::app()->session['uniqueid'];
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Yii' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\wamp\www\bid\protected\components\UserIdentity.php on line 18

Comment: Have you tried placing this within the constructor or in a callable function?

Comment: where did you use that code?

Comment: in a sign up model aftersavefunction()

Answer (score 0):

You can not call this assignment (`Yii::app()->session['uniqueid'] = $this->username;`) from outside the function. Transfer session assignment inside the method.
You also need to make sure that the property `username` is declared in the class.